# Filter duplicate out of array if exist in another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I have 2 PHP array's that contain names.  The first array contains over 100,000 keys

The second array is only 10,000 or less keys

I need to filter out any names from my 10,000 key array if the key exist in the master 100k array

So I will end up with a 3rd array that will contain the 10,000 key array minus any items that existed in the main array.

This is kind of confusing for me to explain so I hope I make sense here.  If you can help I would appreciate it.

A sample array might look like this (both arrays will be in same format)

```
array(
    'Coders4africa',
    'uiri00',
    'phileverson',
    'nileshgr',
    'MSVenom',
    'dshafik',
    'rafavilar'
)
```

Comment: Checking each key of the 10k up against each of the 100k values is the only option, it would take a lot of iteration, and time!

Comment: -1, unclear, self conflicting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_diff($array1, $array2)
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/array_diff): returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: or in this case you'd want to use `array_diff_key` if you're only looking for duplicate keys.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, he's talking about keys, but in the sample array there are only values.

Comment: @Maerlyn you are right I wrote it wrong but thanks for the answer